# Excel chart - how to change all references to another sheet?

Tags: excel-2003

I have a chart in Excel that references a lot of data from Sheet1. About a hundred data series.

It was very time consuming putting that chart together, and there are still 28 of them to go. The data for each one of them is in the same place, but in different sheets.

What would be an intelligent way to change all those references from Sheet1 to Sheet2, while not changing anything else?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a tutorial, [Change Series Formula – Improved Routines](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/change-series-formula-improved-routines/), about the Excel chart series formula, including some VBA routines to modify the formula. You can use the posted VBA routines yourself, and they're included in my commercial Excel add-in software.

In its simplest form, the routine to change the series formulas in a chart goes like this:

```
Sub ChangeChartSeriesFormulas(cht As Chart, sOldString As String, sNewString As String)

  Dim srs As Series, sOldFmla As String, sNewFmla As String

  For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection

    sOldFmla = srs.Formula
    sNewFmla = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sOldFmla, sOldString, sNewString)
    srs.Formula = sNewFmla

  Next srs

End Sub
```

Call this from your code that determines which chart(s) to change and asks the user for find and replace strings.

To do the active chart:

```
ChangeChartSeriesFormulas ActiveChart, "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
```

To do all the charts on the active sheet:

```
Dim chob As ChartObject
For Each chob In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
  ChangeChartSeriesFormulas chob.Chart, "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
Next
```

Comment: Great Idea, Saved me lot of time, +1 for your efforts.